# Can SAP commerce cloud (Hybris) export content?

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

I'd like to verify if SAP commerce cloud (Hybris) has the ability to export its contents automatically?
DynamicYield would like to automatically ingest that content feed using it's [variation feed](https://support.dynamicyield.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034633733-Syncing-Variations-with-a-Variation-Feed).  Is there a way to trigger that export whenever there is a change in the store content or periodically.

Answer (score 2):

You can expose a new occ enpoint:

1. Extend OCC https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/e5d7cec9064f453b84235dc582b886da/8b96a80f8669101482d4f3c1e27b4eb6.html?version=2105
2. Create a new controller which will expose your DTO to Internet. Protect with OAuth2 credential by creating a specific client_id.