# App for transporting SAP Commerce content between environments

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

We have a request from our business to create a custom application capable of extracting CMS content out of one SAP Commerce environment and loading it up into another SAP Commerce environment. The idea is that our content admins could "transport" a new page from QA to production without having to manually recreate it. Also, such a tool could be used in "refreshing" certain parts of one environment with the content of another.

I believe that we could write such a tool ourselves, and I found one other stackoverflow post mentioning a technique to do this:
[Can SAP commerce cloud (Hybris) export content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71456206/can-sap-commerce-cloud-hybris-export-content)

We could create an OCC endpoint for both retrieving cms content and putting cms content.

My question to you all is does there exist a third party application that could do this for us already? It would be beneficial to our organization if we could purchase a solution that did this for us rather than writing and maintaining the app ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

SAP just released an extension for db sync, check [here](https://github.com/SAP/sap-commerce-db-sync).

Comment: Hmm, very intriguing. Not sure if this will do exactly what we're looking for, but I'll take a look into this. Thank you!